# Populate dropdown based on logged in user created records

Tags: mongodb, templates, meteor, dropdown, meteor-blaze

How do I populate a dropdown with records/documents created by the logged in user? I have a collection that many users can create schools. I want it to be that if a user that have created more than a school the dropdown should show populated with the number of schools. If it is only one, the `_id` of the school should just be passed to a hidden field.

This is the school collection:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        SchoolRegister: function (newschoolname, newschoolmotto, newschholvision, sellschool, schooltype, 
            schoolfeerange, schoolcurriculum) {
            if (!Meteor.userId()) {
                throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorized', 'You must be logged in to add a new school!');
                return false;
            }else{
                var regUsername = Meteor.user().username;
                var year = new Date().getFullYear();
                var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
                var day = new Date().getDate();
                var date = (month +"/" +day +"/" +year).toString();

    var schoolId =  NewSchoolDB.insert({
                    newschoolnamevar: newschoolname,
                    newschoolmottovar: newschoolmotto,
                    newschholvisionvar: newschholvision,
                    sellschoolvar: sellschool,
                    schooltypevar: schooltype,
                    schoolfeerangevar: schoolfeerange,
                    schoolcurriculumvar: schoolcurriculum,
                    createdAt: new Date(),
                    author: regUsername,
                    authorId: Meteor.userId()
                    
                });
                    return schoolId;
            }
        },

        UserRecords: function () {
            if (!Meteor.userId()) {
                throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorized', 'You must be logged in to add a new school!');
                return false;
            }else{
                //var UserDocuments = NewSchoolDB.find({authorId: Meteor.userId()}).count();
                    return NewSchoolDB.find({authorId: Meteor.userId()});
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using this to call the method:

```
Template.SchoolContactLayout.helpers({
    UsersDocuments: function () {
        return Meteor.call('UserRecords');
        console.log(Meteor.call('UserRecords'));
    }
});
```

This is the template file

```
{{# if UsersDocuments == 1 }}
                <input type="hidden" name="schoolId" value="{{ UsersDocuments._id }}">
            {{else}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" name="schoolnames" id="schoolnames" required style="color: black; width: 100%; font-family: 'candara'">
                        <option value="{{UsersDocuments._id}}">{{UsersDocuments.newschoolnamevar}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            {{/if}}
```

All in all, no error was returned and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor.call('UserRecords') is Async function you have to wait for it in a callback and use session instead.

```
Meteor.call('UserRecords', function(err,res){
// res will be your return value you can set your session here
});
```

or you can use package for example you can search atmosphere for reactive method